# removeObjectForKey doesn't remove value from .plist

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist

I am developing iPhone app in which i have TableView,

What i want to do is On click of UITableViewCell i want to remove this values from plist, `MOBILES.Brand.2` and `MOBILES.Brand.5` if they exist in .plist if they doesn't exist in .plist then i want to add it to my .plist

Here is the structure of my .plist:

[image]:
Here is my code snippet:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       plistPath = [self getPlistPath];

//PlistDict is mutableDictionary contains the keys and values of .plist (of above image) 
if ([PlistDict valueForKeyPath:@"MOBILES.Brand.2"] != nil) { //if key and it's value exists in Filter.plist

//Delete Key from .plist...
                NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
                [savedStock removeObjectForKey:@"MOBILES.Brand.2"];
                [savedStock removeObjectForKey:@"MOBILES.Brand.5"];
                [savedStock writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

}else{



//Add Key to .plist
            NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
            [data setValue:@"251" forKeyPath:@"MOBILES.Brand.2"];
            [data setValue:@"298" forKeyPath:@"MOBILES.Brand.5"];
            [data writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

    }
}

-(NSString*)getPlistPath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Filter.plist"];
    PlistDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    return path;
}
```

after writing above code snippet it doesn't remove the keys from .plist but it adds the key successfully if not existed.

**Where i am doing mistake ? please help and thanks in advance.**

Comment: Where is the `.plist` file located?

Comment: Where is your plist's location? It in app bundle or it is created programmatically in runtime?

Comment: .plist file is located in app document directory, see my EDIT

Comment: Well that code won't even compile will it, so please update it with code that will.

Comment: Where do u get error ? i have edited the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to remove using the `NSMutableDictionary keypath` directly using `removeObjectForKey` that requires the `exact key` not `keypath` and you are supplying a `keypath`. Use the following `NSMutableDictionary Category` taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15106397/790842)

```
@interface NSMutableDictionary (Additions)
- (void)removeObjectForKeyPath: (NSString *)keyPath;
@end

@implementation NSMutableDictionary (Additions)

- (void)removeObjectForKeyPath: (NSString *)keyPath
{
    // Separate the key path
    NSArray * keyPathElements = [keyPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    // Drop the last element and rejoin the path
    NSUInteger numElements = [keyPathElements count];
    NSString * keyPathHead = [[keyPathElements subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){0, numElements - 1}] componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
    // Get the mutable dictionary represented by the path minus that last element
    NSMutableDictionary * tailContainer = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPathHead];
    // Remove the object represented by the last element
    [tailContainer removeObjectForKey:[keyPathElements lastObject]];
}

@end
```

It should work for you.

**Method - 2**

If the above doesn't work, you can do an iteration of your dictionary, and specifically delete the object for the key.. Try

```
NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

NSMutableDictionary *brand=[[savedStock objectForKey:@"MOBILES"] objectForKey:@"Brand"];

[brand removeObjectForKey:@"2"];
[brand removeObjectForKey:@"5"];
```

Cheers.

Comment: what is `keyPath` here `- (void)removeObjectForKeyPath: (NSString *)keyPath` ? in my case `MOBILES.Brand.2` ?

Comment: The one you are using that is `MOBILES.Brand.2` is keypath you are accessing the object directly, where as `key` are `MOBILES`, `Brand` and `2`. The combination of all keys is keypath.

Comment: I gets this exception `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key MOBILES` when i give key path as `MOBILES.Brand.2`

Comment: Be aware that the nested arrays are currently immutable in the OPs code so you should deal with that.

Comment: still doesn't work when i try to Log brand dictionary: it shows the same key as before

Comment: @Krunal Ok just change `[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]` to `@"2"` and `[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]` to `@"5"`, they are string not number. Updated the answer.